# Estou com um erro na minha response do meu Controller de Symphony

Tags: php, ajax, json, symfony

O meu objetivo é o seguinte, no meu Form ouve uma tentativa de envio em um dos campos que estava vazio,
algo deste genero.  V

Exemplo -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIof9.gif

exepction - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNIaR.jpg

Controler V

```````````````
<?php
// src/Controller/DefaultController.php
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\EmailType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(Request $request)
            {
                $array[] = [
                    "text" => "Band"];
                $array[] = [
                    "text" => "Tour",];
                $array[] = [
                    "text" => "Contact",];
                $array[] = [
                    "text" => "Merchandaise",];

                $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                            ->add('name', TextType::class,array(
                                'required'=>false,
                        'attr'=> ['class' => 'w3-input w3-border']))
                            ->add('email', EmailType::class,array(
                                'required'=>false,
                        'attr'=> ['class' => 'w3-input w3-border']))
                            ->add('message', TextareaType::class,array(
                                'required'=>false,
                        'attr'=> ['class' => 'w3-input w3-border']))
                            ->add('send', SubmitType::class,array(
                        'attr'=> ['class' => 'w3-input w3-border w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right']))
                            ->getForm();

                    return $this->render('body.html.twig' , [
                    'arrays' => $array,
                    'form' => $form->createView(), 
                ]);
           }

    public function indexN2(Request $request)
        {
            $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('name', TextType::class,array(
        'attr'=> ['class' => 'w3-input w3-border']))
            ->add('email', EmailType::class,array(
        'attr'=> ['class' => 'w3-input w3-border']))
            ->add('message', TextareaType::class,array(
        'attr'=> ['class' => 'w3-input w3-border']))
            ->add('send', SubmitType::class,array(
        'attr'=> ['class' => 'w3-input w3-border w3-button w3-black w3-section w3-right']))
            ->getForm();

            $form->handleRequest($request);

                if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) 
                {  

                $name = $form["name"]->getData();
                $email = $form["email"]->getData();
                $message = $form["message"]->getData();
                $error = array();

                if(!$name)
                    $error[] = 'name';

                if (count($error > 0))
                {
                return new JsonResponse(array(
                        'status' => 0,
                        'data' => $error,
                    ));
                }
                    $response = 'array';
                }    
                return new JsonResponse(array(
                        'name' => $name,
                        'email' => $email,
                        'message' => $message,
                    ));        
        }
}
``````````````


Ajax V
``````````````

  $("form").submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.

    console.log('pppppp->'+$(this).serialize())
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'index2',
           data: $(this).serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
                console.log(data);
           }
         });
});


`````````````
```````````````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sua validação não está funcionando porque a função `count` também contabiliza elementos vazios de um array.

```
$array = array("" => "");
echo count($array);
// Saída: 1
```

---

**Você pode melhorar sua validação de duas formas.**

Utilizando a função [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php) para "filtrar" o array onde esta 
recebe dois parâmetros, o array e uma callback.

> Quando a callback é omitida todas as entradas do array iguais a
>   **FALSE** serão removidas.

```
if (count(array_filter($error) > 0)) {
    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'status' => 0,
        'data' => $error,
    ));
}
```

Ou utilizar a função [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) para validar um array, que em minha opinião acho mais aconselhável.

```
if (!empty($error)) {
    return new JsonResponse(array(
        'status' => 0,
        'data' => $error,
    ));
}
```

Perceba que usando o `empty` a sua validação fica menor e mais explícita.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda funcionou :D

Comment: De nada, fico feliz em ajudá-lo! xD